# forwardingTarget not called in Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I created project for re-usable scroll view, and I stumbled with a problem that it is quite hard for me to figure out.
`forwardingTarget(for aSelector: Selector!)` somehow it is never called in the subclass of UIScrollView.
This is a snippet:

```
// MARK: Overriding

override open func responds(to aSelector: Selector!) -> Bool {

    let respondesToSelector: Bool = super.responds(to: aSelector) ||  _delegate?.responds(to: aSelector) == true

    return respondesToSelector
}

override open func forwardingTarget(for aSelector: Selector!) -> Any? {
    if _delegate?.responds(to: aSelector) == true {
        return _delegate
    }
    else {
        return super.forwardingTarget(for: aSelector)
    }
}
```

To add... there is another problem - for example `scrollViewDidScroll` is not caught by `responds(to aSelector: Selector!)` - in fact almost non of the UIScrollView delegate methods are caught by it. Strangely only 1 method is caught `scrollViewWillEndDraggingWithVelocity:targetContentOffset:`

This project is created as open source. [ReusableScrollView](https://github.com/sumofighter666/ReusableScrollView)

I would appreciate your help and of course contribution.

Comment: FYI - extensions do not actually support overriding methods. It's clearly stated in the Swift book. See the first note at the start of the [Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID151) chapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally in the code I have set up delegate this way:

```
override weak open var delegate: UIScrollViewDelegate? {
    didSet {
        _delegate = delegate as? ReusableScrollViewDelegate
    }
}
```

Which is obviously incomplete. There was missing delegate connected with super class. The correct implementation is as follows

```
override weak open var delegate: UIScrollViewDelegate? {
    get {
        return _delegate
    }
    set {
        _delegate = newValue as? ReusableScrollViewDelegate
        super.delegate = self
    }
}
```